flutter_tts build error: NUGET.EXE not found. CMake Error
I ran into an issue after I did flutter pub add flutter_tts. when building, it immediately started giving a weird CMake build error (which I don't understand), making the build fail. It looks similar to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95898, but that's in a different package. I'm hoping that someone can provide some clues as to what is going on here and how I might be able to fix it. (so I can continue to work on my app). here's the error that I'm encountering:
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
NUGET.EXE not found.
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/flutter_tts/windows/CMakeLists.txt:9 (message):
Please install this executable, and run CMake again.
Please install this executable, and run CMake again.
Error: Unable to generate build files
Exited (1).

I tried to install nuget.exe and add the folder of the location of nuget.exe to PATH, but that didn't fix the issue.

Did you run your project on Windows Desktop?

Can you run nuget help in your cmd? to make sure your nuget added correctly in your path.

I ran it on a laptop with windows 10. Running nuget help to see if it's on the path might help, but the whole adding it to the path didn't help in the end. it just gave me different, and in fact, more complicated CMake build errors. See my answer for my personal definitve solution.

What worked for me:

download nuget.exe from https://www.nuget.org/downloads
put nuget.exe in C:/Windows/System32
restart VSCode
run flutter clean
run flutter pub get
try to start a new debug session. it should work now.

